How do I disable microphone access on expo-camera
I have build an app in React Native Expo. I use expo-camera to scan a QR code but on the first use it also asks for the microphone access on Iphone.
I don't know why it does this because I don't ask for the microphone access in the app.
This is the only permission i get:
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

React.useEffect(() => {
    const checkCameraPermission = async () => {
      try {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        setScanner({ status: 'CAMERA_PERMISSION', permission: status === 'granted' });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    };

    checkCameraPermission();
  }, []);

I don't find a solution to this

Set mute property on Camera.
Source: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/
